# How we select conditionally value from drop down

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My scenario is : if "required" text present in drop down than its should select other wise do further work :
But every its gone in else so,what can i do for select value in it

```
List<WebElement> li = driver.findElements(By.xpath("locator"));
         for(int i=0;i<li.size();i++){
        System.out.println("Total months are-->>>"+ li.get(i).getText());
         for(WebElement element:li){
             if(element.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("string")){
                 element.click();
                System.out.println("work complete");
             }else{
                 System.out.println("thanks");
             }
```

Comment: When debugging, what gets returned when you call `element.getText()`?

Comment: thanks@mrfreester yes i miss getText ketword but now its working fine for me.